# Powershell trying to apply a group to folder which applies to this folder only

Tags: powershell

I have the same issue as "leosenko".
My script is below;

```
$groupperm = @(
('(RW)',$readwrite,$inheritanceFlag,$propagationFlag),
('(RO)',$readonly,$inheritanceFlag,$propagationFlag),
('(LF)',$Listfolder,'None','None'))

foreach ($group in $groupperm){
        $grouptxt = "FS1-$groupname " + $group[0]
        $accessControlEntry = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($grouptxt, $group[1], $group[2], $group[3], $type)
        $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlEntry)
        Set-ACL $folderpath $objACL
        $accessControlEntry
        }
```

The groups get applied to the $folderpath just fine but the "applies to" on the last group instead of being "This folder only" is "This folder, subfolders and files" as per the others.

If I check the ACL with `(Get-ACL $folderpath).Access`
I get

```
FileSystemRights  : Read, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : MELTD\FS1-testing (LF)
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

for the last group, but the output from $accesscontrolentry when I run the script (for the last group) shows;

```
FileSystemRights  : Read, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : FS1-testing (LF)
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Can anyone shed any light for me ?

thanks in advance,

Paul.

## EDIT... ok so after some testing... if I set the permission with

```
icacls $folderpath /grant $grouptxt":(R)"
```

I get the desired "this folder only" permission set, however if I include that line with the script and only apply the first two permissions the same line sets the permission to "this folder, subfolders and files"
e.g.

```
$groupperm = @(
        ('(RW)',$readwrite,$inheritanceFlag,$propagationFlag),
        ('(RO)',$readonly,$inheritanceFlag,$propagationFlag)        
        )
        $grouptxt = 'FS1-'+$groupname+' (LF)'
        icacls $folderpath /grant $grouptxt":(R)"
        
        foreach ($group in $groupperm){
            $grouptxt = "FS1-$groupname " + $group[0]
            $accessControlEntry = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($grouptxt, $group[1], $group[2], $group[3], $type)
            $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlEntry)
            Set-ACL $folderpath $objACL
            $accessControlEntry
            }
```

Something is very broken!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the InheritanceFlags to only ObjectInherit

[Update]

I think I got what you wanted with the following,

```
$ACL = Get-Acl "C:\test"

$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Users","FullControl","ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit","None","Allow")
$ACL.RemoveAccessRule($Rule)
Set-ACL $ACL.Path $ACL

$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Users","FullControl","None","None","Allow")
$ACL.AddAccessRule($Rule)
Set-ACL $ACL.Path $ACL
```

As you can see I had to remove the existing rule first then changing the InheritanceFlag in the second rule changes what is displayed in the Applies to column.

ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit = This folder, subfolders and files
ObjectInherit = This folder and files
ContainerInherit = This folder and subfolders
None = This folder only

I only had a quick play and I'm not that good when it comes to Powershell or any programming so I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah tried that modified the ('(LF)',$Listfolder,'ObjectInherit','None') and re-ran... the variable output shows FileSystemRights  : Read, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : FS1-testing (LF)
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
but when I do a get-acl it shows
FileSystemRights  : Read, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : MELTD\FS1-testing (LF)
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

and the perms remain folders and subfolders

Comment: Yeah I think your theory is correct, however it seems that setting the other two permissions to this folder, subfolders and files changes the list folder groups permissions to also be this folder, subfolder and files regardless of what settings I use. I think in isolation it works fine as I can prove by using icacls $folderpath /grant $grouptxt":(R)" to the list folder group. As soon as I introduce the other two (and in any order) the Applies To changes. I've no idea why, but thanks for your efforts.